# Problem with navigation component multiple back stacks and implement support manually with underlying APIs

Tags: android, navigation

I'm trying to implement support for multiple back stacks with a custom `BottomNavigationView` and not with menu items as with the `BottomNavigationView` provided by `NavigationUI`.

I set my custom BottomNavigationView with a `NavController` acquired by following code snippet

```
val navHostFragment =
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController

bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

and then internally use the `NavController` in my implementation to navigate to different Fragments which is supposed to have separated backstacks.

According to the documentation [Implement support manually with underlying APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/multi-back-stacks#manual) to support multiple back stacks I needed to use

```
app:restoreState=”true”
```

```
app:popUpToSaveState=”true”
```

in my `<action>` elements which I have done.

But what I experienced is

1. Upon app start the `AlphaFragment` is shown as expected,
2. Next I'm navigating to `BetaFragment` with the action `navigate_to_beta_from_alpha` which also works as expected.
3. Tried to navigate back to `AlphaFragment` with the action `navigate_to_alpha_from_beta`, now things are not working as expected. Nothing seems to happen and BetaFragment is still visible on screen.
4. Tried to navigate back to `BetaFragment` again this time the app is crashing with this error.
   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.app:id/navigate_to_beta_from_alpha cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.app:id/betaFragment) label=Beta class=com.example.app.ui.BetaFragment`

From the stacktrace it seems that I still in `BetaFragment.`

If someone can shed a light of why the navigation back to AlphaFragment didn't work would be very helpful.

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/alpha">

    <include app:graph="@navigation/alpha"/>
    <include app:graph="@navigation/beta"/>
</navigation>
```

**alpha.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/alpha"
    app:startDestination="@+id/alphaFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/alphaFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.AlphaFragment"
        android:label="Alpha"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_alpha"/>
    <action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_beta_from_alpha"
        app:destination="@+id/beta"
        app:popUpTo="@id/alphaFragment"
        app:popUpToSaveState="true"
        app:restoreState="true" />
</navigation>
```

**beta.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/beta"
    app:startDestination="@+id/betaFragment"\>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/betaFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.BetaFragment"
        android:label="Beta"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_beta"/\>
<action
        android:id="@+id/navigate_to_alpha_from_beta"
        app:destination="@+id/alpha"
        app:popUpTo="@id/betaFragment"
        app:popUpToSaveState="true"
        app:restoreState="true" /\>
</navigation\>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


    <com.example.app.ui.custom.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```